# Unity Plugin AndroidJavaException NoSuchMethodError on Function with parameters

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins, nosuchmethoderror

I got a very annoying issue. All of my Android plugins in Unity just work if I dont use parameters in the calling functions. I am working on this issue since 2 days and I am slowly running out of ideas. Even a minimal project doesnt work. I am sure Iam doing it right because my functions are working fine without parameters.

Unity:

```
void Start (){
  AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("tnbrtrm.lications.de.myplugin.MyPlugin");
  String test = pluginClass.CallStatic<string>("getMessage", new object[] { "alalalalala" });
  Debug.Log("callShareAppAARPlugin: " + test);}
```

Android:

```
public class MyPlugin extends UnityPlayerActivity {

public static String getMessage(String text)
{ return "Hello World! " + text; }
}
```

My plugin prints "Hello world" correctly when I delete the parameter "String text", but with parameter I get this annoying error:

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method "Ltnbrtrm/lications/de/myplugin/MyPlugin;.getMessage(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;"
```

I see this error using Plugins as *.jar or *.aar. And I also had a look into this packages and my Classes and Functions are there. Otherwise it wouldnt work without parameters... I tried AndroidJavaClass and AndroidJavaObject.

Can anyone please help me? I tried a lot of things... (older JDK versions, etc.) I seems so easy in all the turorials so I assume it has something to do with my system or unity (5.3.5 pro).

Kind regards,

Tino

Comment: For your final code, how many parameters do you expect your `getMessage` function to have in java? Right now, it is one but will that remain one in the future?

Comment: Hi! getMessage is just a minimal implementation for testing. I think my later functions will have more than one parameter but I guess for a good programming style not more than 5. I saw examples with 4 to 5 parameters working for other people... So I dont care about the number of parameters it has to workf with one or 10 parameters! regards, tino

Comment: Ok. I once had your problem. Before I post solution, what unity version are you using?

Comment: Try this `pluginClass.CallStatic<string>("getMessage", "alalalalala" );` and let me know if that works. Also, this used to be a bug and it seems like it is now fixed....Please update unity to [5.4.0F1][1] or above[1]: http://unity3d.com/unity/beta . If after the update and the problem is still there. Let me know if `pluginClass.CallStatic<string>("getMessage", "alalalalala" );`  is working

Comment: Ok I tried both of your suggestions and in combination. But it did not solve the problem, I see the same error in a slightly different format:AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='getMessage' signature='(I)Ljava/lang/String;' in class Ljava.lang.Object;
                                          java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='getMessage' signature='(I)Ljava/lang/String;' in class Ljava.lang.Object;

Comment: This is actually a weird problem. Did you update Unity to the version I linked. Also, please rebuild your jar plugin again and make sure you have the `public static String getMessage(String text)` in the Java side.

Comment: Hi, it is working now. But unfortunately I can not say why. I changed things in too many locations. May be it was the update of Unity and a new JDK version... @Programmer thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: I tried it the first time and only once and it works. I believe that the jar wasn't updating and the old jar was being used. Congrats!

Comment: @Tino I have same problem, How you have fixed?